# How to truncate tables between integration tests?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm pretty new to Java EE and I'm trying to do integration tests on my project. I'm a little confused on how to trucate the tables and mantain the test data between tests. I'm using JPA for persistence, with annotations. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet! I'm trying dbsetup and it works great!